# Multiplicar los dígitos de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

resulta que al analizar este código tan simple, no supe como multiplicar los elementos de una lista, me explico.

```
lista1=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(*lista1, sep='')
```

La salida de ese código es '**12345**', pues resulta que ese número, **quiero multiplicarlo por 4**, tal que el resultado sea **'49.380'**, pero no se como hacerlo.

PD: Los valores dentro de la lista pueden cambiar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basándome en la respuesta del usuario [cval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880813/typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-string-int-found) de **SO en inglés** hacemos:

Procedimiento:

- Uso del método `join()` para que al momento de iterar el vector indiquemos que caracter será el separador entre cada elemento del nuevo resultado, en este caso comillas vacías indica que *cada número estará a lado del otro siguiente*, de modo que **se forme una sola cifra**
- Como el método `join` funciona sobre *strings* entonces cada elemento lo casteamos a una instancia de `str` así: `str(numero)`, en caso de no pasar un valor de este tipo recibiremos un error de tipo **TypeError**
- Al momento de querer imprimir el resultado como recibimos el *string* necesitamos hacer un `cast` de nuevo para que la multiplicación se realice sobre elementos numéricos

Código:

```
lista = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

numeros = ''.join(str(numero) for numero in lista)

print(int(numeros) * 4)
```

Si en la línea donde hacemos el `print` de la multiplicación no casteamos a entero, estaremos recibiendo un valor como este:

> 12345123451234512345

Es decir cuatriplica la cadena de elementos

**Referencias**

- [Método `Join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: @abulafia siento pisar tus dominios :D

Comment: +1 Buena respuesta! Ya que te me has adelantado, doy otra solución aunque me gusta menos ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Aunque prefiero la respuesta de Aprendiz, voy a dar otra alternativa más "aritmética".

Dada la lista `[1,2,3,4,5]` quieres formar con ella el entero 12345. Esto puede resolverse sin necesidad de pasar por una cadena intermedia, si te das cuenta de que:

- El último elemento de la lista (5) representa las unidades, por tanto va multiplicado por 1, es decir 10**0
- El penúltimo (4) son las decenas, por tanto va multiplicado por 10, es decir 10**1
- El anterior (3) son las centenas, por tanto va multiplicado por 100, es decir 10**2
- Ya se ve el patrón ¿no?

Por tanto la siguiente operación te da el valor numérico buscado:

```
n=sum(digito*10**e for e,digito in enumerate(reversed(lista)))
```

Al ser este `n` entero, ya puedes hacer luego `n*4` sin problema.